# How can i prevent field display on sign up while using profile 2 module

Tags: users

In my site, I used the profile 2 module to add some fields to the registration/sign up page.
Is there a way to exclude some of these newly added fields from being displayed at sign up, so that a new user will only see them when he wants to edit his/her profile ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to admin/structure/profiles and click on Edit for the desired profile type, you can configure these settings.

Simply uncheck *Show during user account registration*. You can even eliminate the profile from the account page by checking *Provide a separate page for editing profiles.* .

If you want to restrict access to particular fields only, use the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module and set the *View* permissions on the selected fields to **Authenticated user**. On registration the user is still **Anonymous**, and will not be able to see the fields.

Comment: The "Show during user account registration" option is not available when i try to edit fields created via profile 2. It only shows in fields that are added directly to the core user registration form.

Comment: I don't think that this is what OP want. He wants to show some fields on user registration form and some fields not. There is a way to do that, which I already did in a project. I will post the answer as soon as I have a chance to check how I did it.

Comment: The setting is available for the profile, not the profile fields. For fields only you have to use a field-level access control, like the one I mentioned above. Sorry for the cross purposes, but I had to save the partial answer when I got called away.

Comment: Yes it was exactly what I did in that project. I used Field Permissions to restrict access to the fields on registration form.